# Printing a pdf.js generated document from a webview

Tags: android, printing, webview, pdf.js

I searched a lot but I doesn't found an appropriate question and of course an answer to the following:
I have an activity with a webview displaying a remote pdf, and everything it's working, but when I push the button for printing nothing happens, except the preparation of the document.
Maybe I need to add some permission in the manifest?
The following is the code of the activity, and menuInflater is a simple extention of the AppCompatActivity to create a menu

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class pdfViewer extends menuInflater {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_viewer);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        String nomeFile = ""; // or other values
        if(b != null)
            nomeFile = b.getString("nomeFile");

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        //myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        myWebView.loadUrl(LoginActivity.server+"/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=/pdf/"+nomeFile);

    }
```